# There is no viewcontroller.swift file when I start the project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode11

I tried to start the project and play around with viewcontroller but I do not see it.
Only appdelegate and scenedelegeate and contentview.
The code below was supposed to be added to viewcontroller but I do not know where to add.
It keeps giving me a error message saying unresolved identifier present and action.
please help.

```
    @IBAction func hello() {
        // add alert

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "hello", message: "daaaammmmmn", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)

        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 12):

When you created the project, in the User Interface pop-up, you chose SwiftUI.

[image]

Choose Storyboard instead.

[image]

Comment: Thank you but why alert.addAction(action) is not working?

Comment: it keeps saying it is a unresolved identifier..

Comment: Because your code is not inside the ViewController class declaration? Basically you are now asking me a completely new question. You said: "The code below was supposed to be added to viewcontroller but I do not know where to add" Do what I said to do, and now there is a ViewController as you asked for. Done. If you then have a new question ask a new question.